# SQL query to search by day/month/year/day&month/day&year etc

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with events. Each event has a datetime or an interval. Common data are stored in the `events` table and dates are stored in either `events_dates` (`datetime` field) or `events_intervals` (`starts_date`, `ends_date` both are `date` fields).

Sample datetime events

- I was born on 1930-06-09
- I got my driver's license on 1950-07-12
- Christmas is on 1900-12-24 (1900 is reserved for yearly reoccuring events)

Sample interval events

- I'll be on vacation from 2011-06-09 till 2011-07-23

Now I have a user that will want to look up these events. They will be able to fill out  a form with `from` and `to` fields and in those fields they can enter full date, day, month, year, day and month, day and year, month and year in one or both fields.

Sample queries

- From May 3 to 2012 December 21 will look for events between May 3 and December 21 whose max year is 2012
- From day 3 to day 15 will look for events between the 3rd and 15th day of every month and year
- From day 3 will look for events on the 3rd day of every month and year (same if `from` is empty and `to` is not)
- From May 3 to June will look for events between May 3 and last day of June of every year
- etc.

Any tips on how to write a maintanable query (it doesn't necessarily have to be fast)?

Some things that we thought of

- write all possible `from`, `to` and day/month/year combinations - not maintable
- compare dates as strings e.g. input: `____-06-__` where `_` is a wildcard - I wouldn't have to generate all possible combinations but this doesn't work for intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write maintainable queries that additionally are fast by using the pg/temporal extension:

https://github.com/jeff-davis/PostgreSQL-Temporal

```
create index on events using gist(period(start_date, end_date));

select *
from events
where period(start_date, end_date) @> :date;

select *
from events
where period(start_date, end_date) && period(:start, :end);
```

You can even use it to disallow overlaps as a table constraint:

```
alter table events
add constraint overlap_excl
exclude using gist(period(start_date, end_date) WITH &&);
```

---

> write all possible from, to and day/month/year combinations - not maintable

It's actually more maintainable than you might think, e.g.:

```
select *
from events
join generate_series(:start_date, :end_date, :interval) as datetime
on start_date <= datetime and datetime < end_date;
```

But it's much better to use the above-mentioned period type.